# How do I calculate the amount of watts that a heating element needs inside a box?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, airflow, convection, heat

I have an aluminium box (6 mm thick) of about 13.6 m³.

Inside the box is a ventilator that can move 140 m³/h and I want to keep the temperature inside this box at about 30 °C.  The box is to be placed indoors where the temperature is 20 °C. The fans exchanges air with the outside.

What is the minimum energy source I need in this box?

Comment: Does the fan just circulate the air inside or is it meant to exchange air with the outside

Comment: exchange air with the outside

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I calculate the temperature change inside a box with multiple heat sources?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54270/how-do-i-calculate-the-temperature-change-inside-a-box-with-multiple-heat-source)

Comment: What about similar questions: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/16705/10902, https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/35939/10902

Comment: i did look at the 2 first ones but i did not look at the last one, will se if that helps.

Comment: the secend to last link you sendt is what i need but i cant figure out how to use it, my calculator only gets error massage :(

Answer (score 1):

After some Calculations i ended up using the amount of air (m³/s), air density kg/m³, temperature differance and a mollier diagram to get to my ansver, witch ended up to be around 700W

thanks for all the help guys :)